# Intercepting object returned by private method in a public method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermock

I need to unit test a method, and I would like mock the behavior so that I can test the necessary part of the code in the method.

For this I would like access the object returned by a private method inside the method I am trying to test. I created a sample code to give a basic idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Main.class

```
Class Main {
  public String getUserName(String userId) {
    User user = null;
    user = getUser(userId);
    if(user.getName().equals("Stack")) {
      throw new CustomException("StackOverflow");
    }

    return user.getName();

 }

 private User getUser(String userId) {
  // find the user details in database
  String name = ""; // Get from db
  String address = ""; // Get from db
  return new User(name, address);
 }
}
```

Test Class

```
@Test (expected = CustomException.class)
public void getUserName_UserId_ThrowsException() {
  Main main = new Main();
  // I need to access the user object returned by getUser(userId)
  // and spy it, so that when user.getName() is called it returns Stack
  main.getUserName("124");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to access private:

1. using reflection
2. extend the scope
3. maybe waiting for Java 9 to use new scope mechanisms?

I would change the scope modifier from private to package scope. Using reflection is not stable for refactoring. It doesn't matter if you use helpers like PowerMock. They only reduce the boiler-plate code around reflection.

**But the most important point is you should NOT test too deep in whitbox tests. This can make the test setup explode. Try to slice your code into smaller pieces.**

The only information the method "getUserName" needs from the User-object is the name. It will validate the name and either throw an exception or return it. So it should not be necessary to introduce a User-object in the test.

So my suggestion is you should extract the code retreiving the name from the User-object into a separate method and make this method package scope. Now there is no need to mock a User-Object just the Main-Object. But the method has its minimal information available to work properly.

```
class Main {

    public String getUserName(String userId) {
        String username = getUserNameFromInternal(userId);
        if (userName.equals("Stack")) {
            throw new CustomException("StackOverflow");
        }
        return user.getName();
    }

    String getUserNameFromInternal(String userId) {
        User user = getUser(userId);
        return user.getName();
    }

    ...

}
```

The test:

```
@Test (expected = CustomException.class)
public void getUserName_UserId_ThrowsException() {
  Main main = Mockito.mock(new Main());
  Mockito.when(main.getUserNameInternal("124")).thenReturn("Stack");
  main.getUserName("124");
}
```

Comment: The code in my post was just a sample. Imagine a case where the getUserName uses User object in several ways. Let's say we call about 15 methods of User object in getUserName. But I only want to mock the behavior of one of those method calls. How would I go about it ?

Comment: @bharathp If **one** method is making 15 other calls on some object, then again that is an indication of poor design and somebody not understanding how OO is intended to be used ;-)

Comment: If you call 15 methods in getUserName that doesn't affect the methodology to put the method under test. But as @GhostCat mentioned that this is an indicator of bad design you should question if you are violating the single responsibility principle. But slicing the method in pieces and putting it under test remains the first step to potential refactorings.

Comment: @GhostCat That was just an example, perhaps a bad one :D  Let's say I am trying to build a JSON representation string of an object, that would require me call all the getters of the Object in my buildJSON method. Would that be considered bad design as well ? Assuming that I cannot use any json library.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that call to `new` within your private method.

And the answer is not to turn to PowerMock; or to change the visibility of that method.

The reasonable answer is to "extract" that dependency on "something that gives me a User object" into its own class; and provide an instance of that class to your "Main" class. Because then you are able to simply mock that "factory" object; and have it do whatever you want it to do.

Meaning: your current code is simply hard-to-test. Instead of working around the problems that are caused by this, you invest time in learning how to write easy-to-test code; for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) as a starting point.

Given your latest comment: when you are dealing with legacy code, then you are really looking towards using PowerMockito. The key part to understand: you don't "mock" that private method; you rather look into mocking the call to `new User()` instead; as outlined [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your third paragraph. Unfortunately the code I am testing is legacy code and I won't be spending time on updating it. Many Thanks for the link to the playlist.

Comment: What I meant is: if you would be writing your own code here; then you might want to step back and learn ... how to do that in a "better" way. But when dealing with existing code you can't touch, then PowerMock is the only answer you have there. See my updated answer and its 4th paragraph ;-)

Comment: I do not think it is a question of legacy code and "new" code. In this case the question is white box testing or black box testing. The question is: Do you care about the control flow or do you care about the input parameters that produce certain results without knowing HOW. If you care about the control flow you implicit care about code quality. If you only want to be sure that an object methods produce results matching a specification there is no real handle to enforce code quality as every control flow becomes "implementation detail".

Comment: Of course extending the scope in general is not a good idea. But that is the only way to enforce code quality in detail as long as JAVA hasn't introduced new language mechanics to make whitebox tests easier without extending method scopes. You have other access requirements under test situations and JAVA currently does not adress this. Code quality is not only about object dependencies it is also about control flow. And black box testing inherently denies to look at internals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PowerMock's mockPrivate but I don't recommend it.
If you has such a problem it usually mean that your design is bad.
Why not making the method protected?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that making the method protected is improving the code quality, rather mock the "get from db" part properly.

Comment: @Egor I am not sure if I completely follow, but how does mocking the private method help me create a spy on user object ?